# Xcode - shallow copy in STL string assignment

Tags: c++, xcode, string, c++11, stl

When running the following C++ code in Xcode:

```
std::wstring str1 = L"1111";
std::wstring str2 = str1;

void* ptr1 = (void*)str1.c_str();
void* ptr2 = (void*)str2.c_str();
```

Result is that both pointers are equal. Is this by standard?
In Visual Studio it's not the case.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? I don't get this result with Xcode/clang on mac.

Comment: Xcode 6.3.1 and C++ dialect gnu++11 (compiler option: -std=gnu++11)

Comment: Suggest you use the -stdlib=libc++ option. It's a more conformant implementation and is the default for new projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the implementation is using the *copy-on-write* (COW) optimization, in which a strings internal state is only really set when a write operation is performed<sup>*</sup>. This was allowed in pre-C++11 implementations, but I don't think this is standard since C++11.

Note that you can check that the address of the underlying pointer changes when you access the string in a non-const manner, even without writing to it:

```
str2[0];
```

The evaluation of this expression should trigger a write operation which would change the address of the pointer. Here is a working example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
  std::wstring str1 = L"1111";
  std::wstring str2 = str1;

  std::cout << (void*)str1.c_str() << " " << (void*)str2.c_str() << std::endl;

  str2[0]; // forces a write operation. c_str() changes.

  std::cout << (void*)str1.c_str() << " " << (void*)str2.c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

On a recent gcc, this yields

```
0x8a8e014 0x8a8e014
0x8a8e014 0x8a8e03c
```

---

<sup>* Some non-const accesses can trigger a write even if they don't semantically mutate the string, as shown in the example above.</sup>

Comment: We're using gnu++11 dialect, which isn't fully compatible with C++11, so it's probably the case. Thanks!

Comment: @OferB I don't think the gcc 4 series is standards compliant w.r.t. COW, even in C++11 or C++14 mode. At least it wasn't last time I checked a few months ago.